# Floating visible div inside horizontal scrollable div CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The issue is the following :

I have a calendar in which the user can create an appointment (using DHTMLX Scheduler [Timeline View](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml)), the main problem is the Scheduler doesn't support a scrollable view , only fits the schedule into the view.

I Solve the previous problem, creating a div with a FIXED width (in this way can i have a longer horizontal scheduler ) and wrapping it inside a div that allows to scroll horizontally its content.

**However ,  I dont have a clear idea of how to solve the following problem caused :**

When the calendar is loaded , you can see which div belongs to its horizontal Row
[image: You can see the divs]

And when the user scrolls horizontal (to see 7:00 PM for example)
You cannot see in which div with color you need to create the appointment !

[image: not visible divs]

So i need something like this, where the div is still visible although the user scrolls horizontally :

[image: divs still visible]

I already tried with something like the following : 
**May be a problem too with the parent container, because it hides the div if the following works maybe ?**

```
.visible-division{
    position:relative; /*Because the div with color is inside a table, and i need that still floating in the same row !!*/
    float:left;
    z-index:9000;/*a higher z-index in case something cover the div*/
}
```

without any luck ..

My CSS

```
#calendar-container{
    width: 2000px;
}
#calendario {
    height: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
}
.scrolling_container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And my Markup

```
<div class="scrolling_container">
<div id="calendar-container">
        <div class="dhx_cal_container panel" id="calendario">
            <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
                <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>

                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab"></div>
                <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="timeline_tab" style="right:280px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="well text-right">
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> a link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It can be solved via CSS ? Otherwise, Should I apply classes to it in case of scroll event ?

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) may help you do the trick.

```
  .visible-division{
        position:fixed;
        width: /* specifiy */
        height: /* specify */
        top: /* specify */
        left: /* specify */
    }
    .scrolling_container {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Though not supported by most browser, you may try [sticky](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042) position value `position: sticky`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful, apply this class to the floating div only.

```
.floating{
position:fixed;
top:20px;
right:0px;
width:80%; /* as required */
}
```